# How do I get the 3 executions in this pom.xml file to execute?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm totally lost as to how to get these 3 executions to execute when I perform a `mvn clean install`.  I know they're inside the PluginManagement section, and I feel like that is part of the issue.
Thanks

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>jhu.rahLeague</groupId>
        <artifactId>rahLeague</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>jhu.rahLeagueImpl</groupId>
    <artifactId>rahLeagueImpl</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rahLeagueImpl</name>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>testing</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>!skipTests</name>
                </property>
            </activation>


            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${hibernate3-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                            <extensions>true</extensions>
                            <dependencies>
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                                    <version>${hibernate3.version}</version>
                                </dependency>
                            </dependencies>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>drop-db-before-test</id>
                                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>execute</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                                        <fileset>
                                            <basedir>${basedir}/src</basedir>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>main/resources/ddl/*drop*.ddl</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </fileset>
                                        <onError>continue</onError>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>create-db-before-test</id>
                                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>execute</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                                        <fileset>
                                            <basedir>${basedir}/src</basedir>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>main/resources/ddl/*create*.ddl</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </fileset>
                                        <print>true</print>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>populate-db-before-test</id>
                                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>execute</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                                        <fileset>
                                            <basedir>${basedir}/src</basedir>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>test/resources/ddl/**/*populate*.ddl</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </fileset>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                                <!-- <execution>
                                    <id>drop-db-after-test</id>
                                    <phase>test</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>execute</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <autocommit>true</autocommit>
                                        <fileset>
                                            <basedir>${basedir}/src</basedir>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>main/resources/ddl/**/*drop*.ddl</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </fileset>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution> -->
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${sql-maven-plugin.version}</version>

                            <dependencies>
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                                    <version>${h2db.version}</version>
                                </dependency>
                            </dependencies>

                            <configuration>
                                <username>${jdbc.user}</username>
                                <password>${jdbc.password}</password>
                                <driver>${jdbc.driver}</driver>
                                <url>${jdbc.url}</url>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>

                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId> 
            <version>4.0.4.Final</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.173</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cocoon</groupId>
            <artifactId>cocoon-databases-hsqldb-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency> -->


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Have a look at [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), I think something like `mvn -P testing` should work

Answer (score 0):

You need to also reference the plugin in the `plugins` section of the profile (currently you only have the `maven-compiler-plugin` referenced there) and not just in the `pluginManagement` section.

So your pom would be:

```xml
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>testing</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>!skipTests</name>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <!-- excluded the configuration to keep this as short as possible -->
                        ...
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <!-- etc -->
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    ...
                </plugin>
                <!-- add hibernate3-maven-plugin here. Don't need to   -->
                <!-- define a version or configuration as that has     -->
                <!-- already been done in the pluginManagement section -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <!-- am presuming you would also want the sql-maven-plugin to run -->
                <!-- so you would need to add it here as well                     -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    ...
```

The standard `plugins` section of a POM (and profile) defines what plugins should be executed during the build (and how based on their configuration).

The `pluginManagement` section also contains `plugin` elements in much the same way, except that rather than configuring `plugin` information for this particular project build, it is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one (it can be used to configure the current pom as well). However, this only configures `plugin`s that are actually referenced within the `plugins` element in the children (or the current pom - this is what was missing in your case). The children have every right to override `pluginManagement` definitions.

So generally you would use the `pluginManagement` section to define standard configuration of a plugin, and then activate it in child poms (and override any configuration as required) by referencing the plugin in the standard `plugins` section of the pom.

Maven's documentation on the POM can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html (can explain it much better than me)

Comment: p.s. not sure what version of the hibernate3-maven-plugin you are using but version 3.0 does not have an `execute` goal. The available goals are: hbm2doc, hbm2hbmxml, hbm2dao, query, instrument, run, hbmtemplate, hbm2cfgxml, hbm2ddl, help, hbmlint, hbm2java. Am guessing you might want the `run` goal??